# VOC release 5 demo.m is not working

Tags: xcode, matlab, object-detection, matlab-cvst

I am trying to use Berkeley matlab system for detection and localization of objects in images.
The system can be found here - http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~rbg/latent/

My system is iMac, Matlab 2014a and XCode 5.1.1.

I am trying to run the demo.m file, and this is the output I receive:

> compiling the code...Building with 'Xcode Clang++'. Warning: Maybe you
>   need to call fv_cache('unlock') first?
>
> > In fv_compile at 50   In compile at 48   In demo at 5  Building with 'Xcode Clang++'. MEX completed successfully. Building with 'Xcode
> >     Clang++'. MEX completed successfully. Building with 'Xcode Clang++'.
> >     /Users/intern/Documents/MATLAB/voc-release5/features/features.cc:28:21:
> >     warning: unused function 'max' [-Wunused-function] static inline float
> >     max(float x, float y) { return (x <= y ? y : x); }
> >                         ^ 1 warning generated.
>
> MEX completed successfully. Building with 'Xcode Clang++'. MEX
>   completed successfully. Building with 'Xcode Clang++'. MEX completed
>   successfully. Building with 'Xcode Clang++'. MEX completed
>   successfully. Building with 'Xcode Clang++'. MEX completed
>   successfully. Error using mex Unknown MEX argument '-o'.
>
> Error in compile (line 64)   eval([mexcmd ' gdetect/fconvsse.cc -o
>   fconv']);
>
> Error in demo (line 5) compile;

Any help appreciated,
Thanks,
Oz Radiano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit that eventually I used Matlab [computer vision toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/computer-vision/), which uses Viola-Jones Haar features to detect faces ([they claim](http://www.mathworks.com/products/computer-vision/features.html#feature-detection-extraction-and-matching) that they have other trained detectors, which you can look if this is not enough for you). This toolbox made the job for my needs and therefore I left the original problem unsolved.

Regardless, I made some progress with making this detection work before I moved on, and here it is:

I compiled a new Compiler for matlab that will support OpenMP: Wikipedia defines OpenMP as follows:

> OpenMP is an API that supports multi-platform shared memory
>   multiprocessing programming in C, C++, and Fortran, on most processor
>   architectures and operating systems, including Solaris, AIX, HP-UX,
>   Linux, Mac OS X, and Windows platforms

The training code calls several C code files for performance improvements. The problem is that the matlab regular compiler (as for Matlab 2014a) [does not support OpenMP](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014a/index.html), and therefore there's a need to compile a compiler that supports OpenMP and let matlab direct to it. I installed gcc48 from macports, and changed the matlab mexopts.sh file to point to the new compiler.

Hope it helps anyone, just keep in mind I didn't do it end-to-end, but left it and moved to matlab computer vision toolbox.

Comment: `vision.CascadeObjectDetector` indeed comes with several pre-trained detectors: frontal faces, profile faces, upper body, eyes, nose, mouth. You can also train your own detector using `trainCascadeObjectDetector` function.  There is also `vision.PeopleDetector` for detecting people.

Answer (score 0):

```
eval([mexcmd ' gdetect/fconvsse.cc -o fconv']);
```

Replace `-o` with `-output` and your system will run perfectly.